# How do I get an IP address by providing a local host name in flutter dart?

Tags: flutter

Each time when code gets executed I got this error

SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 192.168.29.246, port = 45946

Comment: Don't pass localhost as a string. Go to your network preferences (As per your OS). Now you will be able to see the IP address. Just pass copy and paste the IP address with a port like 192.0.13.125:5000

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Ashish  thanks for the response , I got the ip's in a list  and need to hit the service please see the below code